# 100% width inside an overflow-x: auto element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to simulate a tab control that shows a horizontal scroll bar when needed.

I posted a simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/e8My6/

I have a footer div beneath the tabs, which I would like to always extend horizontally to the entire width of the outer, scrolling div.

However, it only takes on the width of the *client rectangle* of the outer div, rather than all of its contents.

Is there a pure-CSS way to make the footer take the full width?

Answer (score 0):

the 100% must be inherited from something, so you can create a wrapper for all elements in outer div and give it a needed width. then footer will inherit it. but I think you'll be unable to do that so you can assign width with javascript, base on sum of widths of all elements in outer div